# Emit event from other class than native module class from android to react-native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-bridge, react-native-modules

i have CameraModule.kt which is android native module and CameraHomeFragment in a react-native app. And i need to send some data from the fragment to react-native

CameraModule.kt :

```
class CameraModule(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext): ReactContextBaseJavaModule(reactContext) {

  override fun getName(): String = "CameraModule"

  private val context = reactApplicationContext

  @ReactMethod
  fun openCamera(){

    val intent = Intent(context,CameraActivity::class.java)
    if(intent.resolveActivity(context.packageManager) != null){
      intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
      context.startActivity(intent)
    }
  }

  fun emitEvent() {
    context.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter::class.java)
      .emit("eventName", "params")
  }

}
```

CameraHomeFragment.kt :

```
class CameraHomeFragment : Fragment() {

  private var viewBinding: FragmentCameraHomeBinding? = null

  override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
  ): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    viewBinding = FragmentCameraHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return viewBinding?.root
  }

  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    viewBinding?.imageCaptureButton?.setOnClickListener {
      // emit an event here on clicking button
    }
  }
}
```

Have read the docs [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android#sending-events-to-javascript), but did not said how to send event from other class where react application context is not available. How to do it?